# Try to insert or edit data then got error in admin of joomla 3

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have a `joomla 3 application` onto which, after logging as administrator, I show some data `listing` which the users filled up from the front end.

I list those data in the admin panel, but when I tried to edit them or insert new data, then the below `error display` shows up and no data is saved.

```
Warning

Invalid field: Menuscript Title

Invalid field: Area Reasearch

Invalid field: Author Name
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

try to login in your PhpMyAdmin (or any similar) and see if the table where you are trying to add the data really has those fields. If it doesn't you can add them manually.

Comment: I already mention in question that users filled up data in front site but in admin when i tried to edit or insert new then error. Make sense